# Trigger not working in PLSQL while retrieving new value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that multiplies that salaries of employees who're paid more than 1000$ by 2 but it displaying me this error below, here's the code. I'm still discovering this "new/old" concept. But I don't see why my trigger isn't working. Does anybody know why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MAJ
AFTER UPDATE on EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
begin
IF (:new.salary <1000) THEN
:new.salary:= :new.salary*2;
end;
/
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have an `END IF;`

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting an `END IF` in your code -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MAJ
AFTER UPDATE on EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF (:new.salary <1000) THEN
        :new.salary := :new.salary*2;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks , I have another question if you can. Since I can only post 1 question every 90mins, I'm working basically on another function now. Do you have any idea why it's no working? here's the code:             
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_DOUBLE (a number)
RETURN number
IS
BEGIN
a:=a*2;
RETURN a;
END;
/

Comment: You can just replace your parameter list from `(a number)` to `(a in out number)`.